# Basic power set expression problem given $|a|=m,|b|=n,|A \cap B|=k$ express $|P(A \cup B)-(P(A) \cup P(B))|$ using $k,m,n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> This is a basic power set expression problem given $|a|=m,|b|=n,|A \cap B|=k$ express $|P(A \cup B)-(P(A) \cup P(B))|$ using $k,m,n$

---

I tried the following:

$|A-B|=|A|-|A \cap B|$

$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$

$|P(A \cup B)|=2^{|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|}=2^{m+n-k}$

so we need to find $|P(A \cup B)-(P(A) \cup P(B))|$
and this is equal to $|P(A \cup B)| - |P(A \cup B) \cap (P(A) \cup P(B))|$

but I got stuck even though I know that $|P(A \cup B)|=2^{|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|}=2^{m+n-k}$

thanks for any help and tips

Comment: @JeanMarie It is ok ! I did state it is a power set though, anyway thanks for your replies

Comment: same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2753562/305862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question, @Adamrk!

Is the answer $2^{m+n-k} - 2^m - 2^n + 2^k$?

Here is the thought behind the math:

$P(A \cup B) - (P(A) \cup P(B))$ means discounting those sets from $P(A \cup B)$ where all elements of the set belong to only one of $A$ or $B$.

Coming to the math:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then, $|X - Y| = |X| - |X \cap Y|$, and this is as simple as it gets.

But in our case, $X = P(A \cup B)$ and $Y = P(A) \cup P(B)$

$\implies |P(A \cup B) - (P(A) \cup P(B))| = |P(A \cup B)| - |P(A \cup B) \cap (P(A) \cup P(B))|$

[**I think this is the part you were missing**]

By union over intersection, i.e. $X \cap (Y \cup Z) = (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Z)$,

$P(A \cup B) \cap (P(A) \cup P(B)) = (P(A \cup B) \cap P(A)) \cup (P(A \cup B) \cap P(B))$

$\implies P(A \cup B) \cap (P(A) \cup P(B)) = P(A) \cup P(B)$

$\implies |P(A \cup B) - (P(A) \cup P(B))| = |P(A \cup B)| - |P(A) \cup P(B)|$

Now for the simplification,

$|P(A \cup B)| = 2^{m + n - k}$

$|P(A)| = 2 ^ m$ (these are the number of sets where all elements belong to $A$)

$|P(B)| = 2 ^ n$ (these are the number of sets where all elements belong to $B$)

Both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ repeat sets from $P(A \cap B)$.

$\implies |P(A) \cup P(B)| = |P(A)| + |P(B)| - |P(A \cap B)|$

$\implies |P(A) \cup P(B)| = 2^m + 2^n - 2^k$

$|P(A) \cup P(B)|$ is the number of elements we want to discount from $P(A \cup B)$

$\implies |P(A \cup B) - (P(A) + P(B))| = 2^{m + n - k} - (2^m + 2^n - 2^k)$

$\implies |P(A \cup B) - (P(A) + P(B))| = 2^{m + n - k} - 2^m - 2^n + 2^k$

Hope this helps! :)